# Firebase `onAuthStateChanged` always return null user

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

This is my `index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <head>
        <link rel='icon' href='favicon.ico' type='image/x-icon'/ >
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./utilities/css/stylesTopNav.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./utilities/css/stylesLoader.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./utilities/css/stylesLogin.css">
        <title>Login</title>
        <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.2.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
        <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.2.0/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
        <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.2.0/firebase-storage.js"></script>
        <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.2.0/firebase-auth.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body style="background:url(./utilities/images/waterBGGif.gif) fixed; background-size: cover;">
        <div class="container" id="containerID">
            <label for="Email"><b>Email</b></label>
            <input id="emailID" type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" required>

            <label for="psw"><b>Password</b></label>
            <input id="passwordID" type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" required>

            <button type="submit" id="loginButtonID" onclick="loginButtonAction('')">Log In</button>
        </div>

        <script src="./utilities/js/firebase.js"> </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And this is my `firebase.js`:

```
var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "*******************",
    authDomain: "*******************",
    databaseURL: "*******************",
    projectId: "*******************",
    storageBucket: "*******************",
    messagingSenderId: "*******************",
    appId: "*******************"
  };
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

var firestore = firebase.firestore();
var firestorage = firebase.storage().ref();

function logOutButtonAction() {
  const logOutBtn = document.getElementById('logoutButtonID');
  firebase.auth().signOut();
  firebaseStateChange()
}

function loginButtonAction() {
  const txtEmail = document.getElementById('emailID');
  const txtPass = document.getElementById('passwordID');
  const logInBtn = document.getElementById('loginButtonID');

  const email = txtEmail.value;
  const password = txtPass.value;
  const auth = firebase.auth();

  const promise = auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
  promise.catch(e => console.log(e.message));
  firebaseStateChange()
}

function firebaseStateChange() {
  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    window.location.href = "product.html";
  } else {
    window.location.href = "index.html";
  }
  });
}
```

And I have added the email in Firebase Authentication:

[image]

But my `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user)` is always returning null. What I am missing here?

Comment: If you replace the `window.location.href = ....` statements with `console.log(user)`, what output do you get in the console?

Comment: It's always `null`

Comment: Can you update your question to show exactly what you've done, and exactly what the output is? The reason I'm asking is that it is normal for the `onAuthStateChanged` listener to first be called with `null`, but if the user is signed in it will be called with an actual user later (once Firebase has verified the authentication state).

Comment: When I give a break point at ‘onAuthStateChanged’ I am getting the user as null.

Comment: I’m trying to log in my user from index page. And in firebase.js I have placed the login and logout button. Actually I have added that user manually from firebase console and it’s logged for the first try. But since then it is not getting logged and always return user as null. I have tried with other browser as well, but same result.

Comment: Please replace the `window.location.href = ....` statements with `console.log(user)`, update your question, and show the exact output.

Comment: I have figured out the problem. I was calling the `firebaseStateChange()` function just right after `auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)` but I should have waited for the success response and then call the `firebaseStateChange()` function. Thanks a lot for your response Sir. :)